# Why does VideoCapture take 2-3 seconds to open and close?

Tags: c++, opencv

Getting OpenCV Matrix from Macbook/Windows Desktop
Using Huawei/Ubuntu and Ezcap 331 and HDMI cable

C++ chunk to get CV::Mat is  below:

```
cv::VideoCapture cap(2);
cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920);
cap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080);
cv::Mat frame;
cap.read(frame);
```

It gets matrix, but it takes 2-3 seconds to get one frame

Before I used other code for Windows, please find description below:

```
hwnd2Mat::hwnd2Mat(HWND hwindow, float scale)
{
    hwnd = hwindow;
    hwindowDC = GetDC(hwnd);
    hwindowCompatibleDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hwindowDC);
   SetStretchBltMode(hwindowCompatibleDC, COLORONCOLOR);
    RECT windowsize;
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &windowsize);
   srcheight = windowsize.bottom;
    srcwidth = windowsize.right;
    height = (int)(windowsize.bottom * scale);
    width = (int)(windowsize.right * scale);
    image.create(height, width, CV_8UC4);
    hbwindow = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hwindowDC, width, height);
    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.biWidth = width;
    bi.biHeight = -height;
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;
    SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow);
    read();

}

void hwnd2Mat::read()
{
    StretchBlt(hwindowCompatibleDC, 0, 0, width, height, hwindowDC, 0, 0, srcwidth, srcheight, SRCCOPY); //change SRCCOPY to NOTSRCCOPY for wacky colors !
    GetDIBits(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow, 0, height, image.data, (BITMAPINFO*)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);  //copy from hwindowCompatibleDC to hbwindow
}

hwnd2Mat::~hwnd2Mat()
{
    DeleteObject(hbwindow);
    DeleteDC(hwindowCompatibleDC);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwindowDC);

}
```

If I save matrix to file, file's size within 500 kb

Also, there is also a bug, which considered not important in some web resources

[ WARN:0] global ../modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp (935) open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Cannot query video position: status=0, value=-1, duration=-1

It can cause the freeze too

Please advise

Comment: Are you doing all of that for each frame? Most of it looks like initialization, which can take time on any capture device. Have you timed successive frame captures? _e.g._ read one frame, then measure the time it takes to read a second frame by only calling `cap.read(frame);`

Comment: yes, it might be the issue! How to declare cv::VideoCapture as global?

Comment: [crosspost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266159): https://forum.opencv.org/t/opencv-freezing/14010

Comment: same discussion happened on IRC. user reopens the device for every frame. advised to not do that.

Comment: has your programming class covered loops yet?

Comment: It doesn't need to be a global. You've already demonstrated a form of encapsulation with your `hwnd2Mat` class. It's the same principle: make `cv::VideoCapture` a class member and initialize it in the constructor. Read about initializer lists, if you need it to be directly constructed in the way you're currently doing. Your constructor finalizes the setup (frame size _etc_), and then your `read` method simply wraps the `cv::VideoCapture::read()` call.

Comment: yes, when it gets constructed it consumes execution time